# Memorized transaction in Netsuite using SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

[image: Sales order (Transaction) form]

Netsuite provides a way in which we can create memorized transaction using the application or front-end... Is it possible to create a memorized transaction in netsuite using suitescript 2.0.?

Answer (score 1):

No unfortunately memorized transactions are not supported in SuiteScript

Answer (score 0):

well i just figured out a way which helped me in replicating memorized transaction by suite script 2.0.

By using record.copy() function in Scheduled script, it is possible.

```
invoiceObject = record.copy({
    type: record.Type.INVOICE,
    id: <internal id of invoice to copy>
});

//update invoice record fields if you want

invoiceObject.save();
```